# Could you inject external gamma waves into your brain safely?

Tags: brain, brain-waves

I've recently taken up the study of neurology, and I was wondering if you could create a device that would input gamma waves into your brain. And if it would be safe. Suppose you had a device that you wore sort of like a headband, and it emitted gamma waves and focused them into your brain. Would this be safe, if at low power? And would it increase focus/awareness?

Comment: If the answer is "yes": it's safe and cheap to do (insert anything) and this is know to (have positive effect), then why would everyone not already be doing it? See also https://xkcd.com/808/

Comment: @BryanKrause That's a good point. However, people could not be doing it for a number of reasons, such as the fact that it could be expensive, or difficult to set up, or even just  the fact that nobody knows about the (potential) technology.

Comment: If no one knows then your question is not answerable and is speculative. As such, I've voted to close as opinion-based. The question also doesn't show evidence of prior research. I think if you study a bit more what is out there and what is being done, you could ask a good answerable question on the topic. Maybe start with looking into tDCS and TMS.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that the question is not about electromagnetic gamma light radiation, but rather about the gamma frequency brain waves. While we do not "*inject gamma waves*" we can stimulate brain activity at gamma level frequencies through the use of sensory stimulation that occurs at such a frequency. There has been research done with people who have Alzheimer's and the use of lights that turn off and on at the same frequency as Gamma waves.

Here are the respective wikipedia articles that concern gamma waves vs gamma rays respectively
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_wave
**vs**
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray#:~:text=A%20gamma%20ray%2C%20or%20gamma,imparts%20the%20highest%20photon%20energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_ray#:%7E:text=A%20gamma%20ray%2C%20or%20gamma,imparts%20the%20highest%20photon%20energy).

I found the following articles about the use of gamma frequency stimulation in Alzheimer patients.

Here is a link to an article: [https://www.nia.nih.gov/news/noninvasive-brain-wave-treatment-reduces-alzheimers-pathology-improves-memory-mice#:~:text=Previously%2C%20researchers%20at%20the%20Massachusetts,also%20boosted%20the%20activity%20of](https://www.nia.nih.gov/news/noninvasive-brain-wave-treatment-reduces-alzheimers-pathology-improves-memory-mice#:%7E:text=Previously%2C%20researchers%20at%20the%20Massachusetts,also%20boosted%20the%20activity%20of)
Noninvasive brain wave treatment reduces Alzheimer's pathology, improves memory in mice

Here is an article that mentions the use of sound waves at a gamma frequency too.

https://www.alzforum.org/news/research-news/flash-beep-gamma-waves-stimulate-microglia-memory
Flash! Beep! Gamma Waves Stimulate Microglia, Memory

Comment: You may be right about the meaning of gamma wave, but I think we have to be carefule here. From the references above about gamma wave stimulation, the experimenters emit light and/or sound waves at 40-Hz into the mouse brain, thereby enhancing the brain’s 40-Hz gamma waves. As a result of the brain’s gamma wave enhancement, memory and some brain pathology improve. However, although the frequency of the input waves is 40-Hz, they do not call their 40-Hz light and sound waves “gamma waves”. And I don’t think it’s the standard to call light or sound waves at 40-Hz as gamma waves.

Comment: true. I have adjusted my post to more clearly reflect this distinction.

Comment: I think your edited answer is probably what the OP wants to know. He might not have phrased the question accurately by asking “Could you inject external gamma waves into your brain safely?” instead of the probably more accurate one: “Could you inject some kinds of external 40-Hz wave into your brain safely (to enhance the brain gamma wave)?”. Let’s see if that’s the case and the OP agree with you and me.

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Could you inject external gamma waves into your brain safely?**

**A:** Yes, nowdays we can  inject external gamma waves into the brain safely, and the procedure has been done routinely in many advanced neuroradiosurgical clinics for decades now – it’s called Gamma Knife or Gamma Knife Radiosurgery.

But the procedure isn’t done to increase focus or awareness – there’s no theoretical background or experimental evidence for that. Instead, the procedure is done to precisely remove a pathologic lesion, such as tumor, arterovenous malformation, and epileptic focus.

This procedure is the procedure of choice when the conventional neurosurgery cannot be performed due to fact that the lesion is too deep down in the brain or too near a vital structure (such as in the middle of the brainstem) or that the patient's age or medical conditon wouldn't allow a conventional neurosurgical procedure.

**References:**

1. [Gamma Knife](https://www.ucsfhealth.org/treatments/gamma-knife)
2. [Gamma Knife Radiosurgery](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/treatments/16559-gamma-knife-radiosurgery)